# Download / backup all soundcloud user data

Tags: backup, soundcloud, user-data

I tried searching for a tool that would download all data related to a soundcloud user (uploaded tracks, likes/collection, reposts, playlists, comments, groups etc), backing it up locally, but haven't had luck so far. The user data format is not crucially important, and could be something like XML or JSON. I guess it wouldn't be hard to create it using their API, but I thought it's strange there's no tool like that already, so I wanted to ask here first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but I'll just gather here a few bits of information that might be useful to somebody eventually. Based on this article https://helgesverre.com/blog/fetch-info-from-soundcloud-api/

First you need to register an app here, where you'll get your client id
http://soundcloud.com/you/apps/new

```
$clientid = "*******"; // Your API Client ID
$userid = "****"; // ID of the user you are fetching the information for
$username = "*****";

// build our API URL
$url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?    url=http://soundcloud.com/{$username}&client_id={$clientid}";
$user_json = file_get_contents($url);

$tracks_url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{$userid}/tracks.json?client_id={$clientid}";
$tracks_json = file_get_contents($tracks_url);

$playlists_url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{$userid}/playlists.json?client_id={$clientid}";
$playlists_json = file_get_contents($playlists_url);

$followings_url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{$userid}/followings.json?client_id={$clientid}&page_size=200"; // 200 is max
$followings_json = file_get_contents($followings_url);

$followers_url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{$userid}/followers.json?client_id={$clientid}&page_size=200"; // 200 is max
$followers_json = file_get_contents($followers_url);

$reposts_url = "http://api-v2.soundcloud.com/profile/soundcloud:users:{$userid}?client_id={$clientid}&limit=1000&offset=0";  // 1000 works
$reposts_json = file_get_contents($reposts_url);
```